# Inequality $\left(\int_0^1 f(x)dx\right) \left(\int_0^1 \frac{1}{f(y)} dy\right) \ge 1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality

Let $f$ be a positive continuous function defined on a closed interval $[0,1]$, then it is true that:
$$\left(\int_0^1 f(x)dx\right) \left(\int_0^1 \frac{1}{f(y)} dy\right) \ge 1$$
I tried to show this by definition using Riemann sum, and also by Darboux sums, but it seems too messy, and I am not completely sure that it will lead me to result. How it should be proved?

P.S. Although this problem looks like a homework problem, I am simply curious of how it could be proved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This follows immediately from the [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#L2):
$$
\left(\int_0^1 f(x)dx\right) \left(\int_0^1 \frac{1}{f(x)} dx\right) \ge \left(\int_0^1 \sqrt{f(x)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{f(x)}} dx\right)^2 = 1
$$

Answer (score 6):

Integrate on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ the inequality
$$
(f(x)-f(y))\cdot\left(\frac1{f(x)}-\frac1{f(y)}\right)\leqslant0.
$$

Comment: That's a very nice trick +1.

Comment: @julien Thanks. Did you just modify your comment? Why?

Comment: I had added "to show to students who learn about multiple integrals" first. But actually,I think it is also worth being shown to people like me who have known Fubini for a long time ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Take $f_1(x) = \sqrt{f(x)}, f_2(x) = {1 \over \sqrt{f(x)}}$. Then Cauchy Schwarz gives $1 = |\langle f_1, f_2 \rangle | \le \|f_1\|_2 \|f_2\|_2$. Squaring gives the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

\begin{align}
&\color{#ff0000}{\int_{0}^{1}\fermi\pars{x}\,\dd x\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over \fermi\pars{x'}}\,\dd x'}
=
\half
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{%
{\fermi\pars{x} \over \fermi\pars{x'}} + {\fermi\pars{x'} \over \fermi\pars{x}}}
\,\dd x\,\dd x'
\\[3mm]&=
\half
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\braces{\vphantom{\Huge A^{A}}\,\bracks{\vphantom{\LARGE A^{A^{A}}}%
\root{\fermi\pars{x} \over \fermi\pars{x'}}
- \root{\fermi\pars{x'} \over \fermi\pars{x}}}^{\,2} + 2\root{\fermi\pars{x} \over \fermi\pars{x'}}\root{\fermi\pars{x'} \over \fermi\pars{x}}\,}
\,\dd x\,\dd x'
\\[3mm]&\color{#ff0000}{\geq \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\dd x\,\dd y = 1}
\end{align}

> $$
> \color{#0000ff}{\int_{0}^{1}\fermi\pars{x}\,\dd x\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over \fermi\pars{x'}}\,\dd x'}
> \geq \color{#0000ff}{1}
> $$